# How to add quick/fast scroller in a RecyclerView in Android app?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview, fastscroll

I'm looking for a way to implement a quick or fast scroller (however you name it) at the right side, similar to Cabinet's app, in a RecyclerView, but can't find anything beyond a library, but I don't really like its design.

May someone help me with the code and/or layout to implement it? Thanks in advance

[image]